# Find the modulus of continuity of a function

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have the following Dirichlet problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases} a(x)Du\cdot Du-b(x)\cdot Du=0 \ \ \ \ \text{in} \ \Omega, \\u(x) = g(x) \ \ \ \ \text{on} \ \partial\Omega. \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Here $\Omega$ is an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$, $a \in C(\bar\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{N \times N})$, $b \in C(\bar\Omega, \mathbb{R}^N)$ and $g \in C(\partial\Omega)$. I make the following assumptions:

1) $a(x)\xi \cdot \xi \geq |\xi|^2$ for $x \in \Omega$ and $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

2) There is a function $\psi \in C^1(\bar\Omega)$ such that $b(x) \cdot D\psi(x) \geq 1$ for $x \in \Omega$.

Now, I define $H(p,x) = a(x)p \cdot p- b(x) \cdot p$

How can I prove (if it is possible) that $H$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
|H(x,p)-H(y,p)| \leq \omega(|x-y|(1+|p|)) \ \ \ \text{for} \ x,y \in \Omega \ \text{and} \ p \in \mathbb{R}^N?
\end{equation}
Here $\omega$ is a modulus, i.e. a function $\omega\colon[0,+\infty[\to[0,+\infty[$ continuous, nondecreasing, and such that $\omega(0) = 0$.

My attempt: 
\begin{align}
|H(x,p)-H(y,p)|&=|a(x)p \cdot p- b(x) \cdot p - a(y)p \cdot p + b(y) \cdot p|\\
&=|(a(x)-a(y))p \cdot p - (b(x)-b(y)) \cdot p|
\end{align}
but I don't know how to proceed from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.